# Stackpanel in a button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, stackpanel

I'm supposed to make a user-control using WPF, and now i'm bumping into a weird problem.

I came up with a kinda weird solution to get an image along with some text in a button, like this:

```
<Button Height="24" Width="100" Name="btn_change">
     <StackPanel Width="90">
           <Image Source="Images\11.png" Width="24" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Panel.ZIndex="-1" Stretch="Uniform"></Image>
           <Label Content="Change" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,-18,0,0" Height="20" Padding="0,0,0,0" />
     </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

This worked perfectly, until i started using a MVVM Framework (Caliburn.Micro). From that point on the images no longer show up in the buttons, just the text. I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Maybe someone with knowledge of MVVM Frameworks can explain this or give me a solution :)

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Never mind! I looked it over thanks to H.B. and it seemed I moved the View to a subfolder. I changed the image source from `"Images\11.png"` to `"..\Images\11.png"` and it worked!

Comment: The image uses a relative path, was the View moved to another folder? Anyway, try `"\Images\11.png"`

Comment: You're absolutely right! How silly of me that I didn't see that...

Comment: @Joris, if you think that you're answer to your problem can help others you can post it as an answer to your own question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Comment: @AdrianFaciu I will when I'm allowed to, I need to wait like 7 hours since I've only just registered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your image source from "Images\11.png" to "..\Images\11.png" and it will work.